# How to configure back-end C# server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, cors, backend

I wanted to ask this question: if I choose C# (ASP.NET) as back-end language for my project, how do I need to configure it to enable CORS to a specific domain? I've been struggling with this issue for days and used everything I found, but at the end using `[EnableCors]` or `Response.Headers.Add()` didn't work at all. Here are my files:
**Server.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;

namespace spider_web.Data;
[ApiController]
[EnableCors()]
//Base class for all back-end interactions. Contains the basic methods for CRUD operations.
public class Server: ControllerBase {
    //Logs user in with token-based authentication.
    public Server() {
        StringValues token = new StringValues("*");
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", token);
    }
    [HttpPost("/login")]
    public void Login(string username, string position, string password) {
        // ...
    }
    //Test method for verifying port connection. List of chars is the arbitrary value.
    [HttpGet("/fetch")]
    public IActionResult Fetch() {
        // None of these worked.
        //Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        //HttpContext.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://localhost:4200";
        return Ok(new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c' });
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using spider_web.Data;



var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//string[] origins = new string[3] { "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:7093", "http://localhost:5226" };


builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Allow-local-host", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddMvc();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Here is the Angular component where I call the back-end:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chars',
  templateUrl: './chars.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chars.component.css']
})
export class CharsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    this.http.get("http://localhost:5226/fetch", {headers}).subscribe(
      response => {console.log(response)}, error => {console.log(error)});
  }
}
```

Thanks all of you in advance!

Comment: Your code creates a **named policy** `Allow-local-host` (as opposed to the _default policy_), but you aren't referencing that named policy anywhere anywhere - so either add an explicit `[EnableCors("Allow-local-host")]` attribute to your Controller classes (or methods) - or make it the default policy by removing the `"Allow-local-host"` name from `AddPolicy`.

Answer (score -1):

This adds a default policy that will work for all of your controllers without the need to add the `[EnableCors]` attribute:

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => builder
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .WithOrigins("https://domain1.com", "https://domain2.com")
        ));
```

You can add many domains, but you would need to repeat them, if you need both the http and the https schemes, as pointed out in the comments.

More on CORS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#dp

Comment: `.WithOrigins("domain1.com", "domain2.com")` <-- This is incorrect. An _Origin_ value must start with a URI prefix (e.g. `http://domain1.com` or `https://domain2.com`) and be repeated for every combination of URI scheme, hostname, and non-default port number, so it's not just a hostname. Assuming we're not using `http:` then change your code to `.WithOrigins("https://domain1.com", "https://www.domain1.com", "https://domain2.com", "https://www.domain2.com")`.